# load data infile Date time in mysql results in zeros

Tags: mysql

can someone help me with this, my resulting table is showing only zeros for the timestamp. I tried changing the field type to datatime and timestamp but not luck

MYSQL

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'vals.csv' 
  INTO TABLE vals
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
  LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
  IGNORE 1 LINES
  (@varTimeSt,NOMINAL,NAME,ID,VAL) SET DATETIME = STR_TO_DATE(@varTimeSt,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s');
```

CSV File

```
DATETIME,NAME,ID,VAL
"25/08/2016 02:00:00",tom,cNum6,12
"25/08/2016 02:00:00",Charles,cNum7,10.58
"25/08/2016 02:00:00",Donal,cNum8,10.18
"25/08/2016 02:00:00",Duncan,cNum7,10.31
```

Resulting table

```
DATETIME,NAME,ID,VAL
0000-00-00 00:00:00,tom,cNum6,12
0000-00-00 00:00:00,Charles,cNum7,10.58
0000-00-00 00:00:00,Donal,cNum8,10.18
0000-00-00 00:00:00,Duncan,cNum7,10.31
```

Comment: I fixed this issue

Comment: I made a silly mistake, the dates are enclosed                                       LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'vals.csv' 
      INTO TABLE vals
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
      OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
      LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
      IGNORE 1 LINES
      (@varTimeSt,,NAME,ID,VAL) SET DATETIME = STR_TO_DATE(@varTimeSt,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s');

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your dates are not in native mysql `DATETIME` format (`%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s`), this can be shown as such:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('25/08/2016 02:00:00' AS DATETIME);
+-----------------------------------------+
| CAST('25/08/2016 02:00:00' AS DATETIME) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| NULL                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                         |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '25/08/2016 02:00:00' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

The solution is to get them into MySQL format, this could be done by manipulating your `DATETIME` column on disk or at source. This may be more difficult than the 'self sufficient' solution I'll outline below.

There exists the string to date (`STR_TO_DATE`) function to solve this kind of issue once data is inside the database, here is a demonstration with your format. Otherwise see the manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). (See the `DATE_FORMAT` section for a table with the codes you can use for different date formats.):

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(STR_TO_DATE('25/08/2016 02:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS DATETIME);
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(STR_TO_DATE('25/08/2016 02:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS DATETIME) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-08-25 02:00:00                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Personally in this situation I'd load the data into a temporary table that accepted the date fields as a string and then use an `INSERT` with the `STR_TO_DATE`function to get the data into the final table. A final solution (untested, guideline only) would look like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE valsLoad (DATETIME TEXT,NAME TEXT,ID TEXT,VAL INT);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'vals.csv' 
INTO TABLE valsLoad
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@varTimeSt,NOMINAL,NAME,ID,VAL) SET DATETIME = STR_TO_DATE(@varTimeSt,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s');

INSERT INTO vals
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATETIME, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%m'), NAME, ID, VAL FROM valsLoad;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE valsLoad;
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Regards,

James

Comment: Santosh - was this helpful? Please let me know if you require anything else